# Is S={1,2,3,...,10} under the binary operation x∗y=x a group?

Tags: group-theory

I'm a bit confused as to how to go about proving if this is a group. First of all the question says it is a binary operation, but is it? I would've thought a binary operation has to make some of use of both x and y, but this question just says x*y= always x, regardless of y. How would I go about trying to prove this has an identity, since x*e=x for any e? Or would I say that actually y is the identity?

And from there, how would I go about trying to find an inverse? If I say my identity is y, then I would need an inverse B so that x*B=e=y. But since x*y=x, there's no way I could ever actually have x*y=y. Does this mean there is no inverse? Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is no requirement that the result of a binary operation "has to make some use of" both of its inputs. More generally, there is no requirement that a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ "has to make use of both of $x$ and $y$". Think of one of the common functions from multi-variable calculus, the projection onto the $x$-axis, defined by $f(x,y)=x$. That does not make use of $y$, but it certainly is a function. And $x*y=x$ certainly is a binary operation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question might be that it's not a group. Indeed, if there were an identity element $e$, it would have to satisfy $e * n = n * e = n$ for each $n \in S$. But by definition, $e * n = e$, so this would mean that $e = n$ for each $n \in S$.

Answer (score 1):

The operation *is* a binary operation. Contrary to what you expect, the term "binary operation" does not contain a requirement that both inputs are "used" by the operation -- anything that takes two inputs from some set and produces a single output in the same set is a binary operation. It doesn't matter *how* that single output comes about, as long as each pair of inputs will consistently lead to one and only one output.

Your set with this operation is, however, *not a group*, since there is no element that works as an identity for it.

(On the other hand, the operation is *associative*, which is at least something, though it doesn't make it a group operation).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you may stop at the identity (don't bother with inverses), since we should have, for any $x$, that
$$
x=xe=ex=e
$$
and there is clearly no such $e$.

Answer (score 0):

In a group you have to prove that $$xe=x ,\forall x$$ but also $$ex=x ,\forall x$$ And in this case the second identity is never true (you can try every value of S for e).
So since there is no identity element, you can't define an inverse. You only have a semigroup (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).

Comment: Downvoted for abuse of the $\forall$ symbol. No matter which style of punctuation you prefer, quantifiers always go _in front of_ the formula they apply to, so you would write $\forall x. xe=x$ or $(\forall x) xe=x$ or $\forall x(xe=e)$ --  but putting the $\forall x$ to the right of $xe=x$ unambiguously produces nonsense.